# Merge 2 parts of 2 different dataframes separately using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

lets say I have 2 dataframes:

the first dataframe:

| names | val1 | val2 | Nan | names | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 1 | 2 | Nan | user3 | 3 | 4 |
| user2 | 2 | 3 | Nan | user1 | 3 | 3 |

the second dataframe:

| names | val1 | val2 | Nan | names | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 3 | 2 | Nan | user4 | 2 | 1 |
| user2 | 5 | 3 | Nan | user1 | 1 | 5 |

I want to merge these 2 dataframes so that the resultant dataframe is something like this:

| names | val1 | val2 | Nan | names | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 4 | 4 | Nan | user1 | 4 | 8 |
| user2 | 7 | 6 | Nan | user3 | 3 | 4 |
|  |  |  | Nan | user4 | 2 | 1 |

so when the dataframes are merged the values of same users must be added and also the left part of dataframe(i.e the part before the Nan values) must be merged separately from the right part

I know I could do this by dividing each dataframe into two parts and merging them separately but I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have two sides, splitting seems like the easiest approach:

```
tmp1 = (pd.concat([df1.iloc[:, :4], df2.iloc[:, :4]])
          .groupby('names', as_index=False)
          .agg({'val1': 'sum', 'val2': 'sum', 'Nan': 'first'})
       )
tmp2 = (pd.concat([df1.iloc[:, 4:], df2.iloc[:, 4:]])
          .groupby('names', as_index=False).sum()
       )

out = pd.concat([tmp1, tmp2], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   names  val1  val2  Nan  names  val1  val2
0  user1   4.0   4.0  Nan  user1     4     8
1  user2   7.0   6.0  Nan  user3     3     4
2    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  user4     2     1
```

A generic approach to handle an arbitrary number of groups of columns would be much more complex:

```
def dedup(df):
    c = df.columns.to_series().groupby(level=0).cumcount()
    return df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns, c]), axis=1)

out = (pd.concat([dedup(df1).stack(),
                  dedup(df2).stack()])
         .drop(columns='Nan')
         .set_index('names', append=True)
         .groupby(level=[0,1,2]).sum()
         .reset_index('names')
         .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount())
         .set_index('n', append=True).assign(Nan=float('nan'))
         .unstack(level=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)
         .sort_index(level=[1, 0])
         .iloc[:, :-1].reset_index(drop=True).droplevel(1, axis=1)
      )
```

Comment: yep I only have two sides in the dataframe, thank you so much!! also if possible could you explain how the second approach works for multiple parts? I'm new to pandas

Comment: The second one detects the duplicated headers, reshapes the dataframes to a long form, merges and reshapes back to the original format. If you want to see how it works, comment everything between the outer `(...)` and uncomment line by line.

Comment: thank you! also I had one more question does the concat function automatically sort data ? because even though we havent called sort_values the data seems to be automatically sorted based on the names column

Comment: @AriesHa no, but `groupby` does, you can pass `sort=False` to keep the original order